# O que é requisito dito funcional e não funcional (qualidade)?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software, requisitos

## Contextualizando a pergunta

Ao estudar sobre engenharia de software a algum tempo atrás, em sala de aula foi pedido uma **explicação formal e informal** a respeito do que seria um **requisito não funcional** junto com um **exemplo** para melhor explicitar o conteúdo.

Ao tentar explicar **com minhas palavras** sobre o conceito de **requisitos não funcionais**, a síntese ficou assim:

**Opção 1**

> Requisito não funcionai é aquele evento que não pode ser previsto, pelo sistema, de forma que o sistema possa não conseguir resolve-lo por ser um evento imprevisível. O Sistema pode resolver o problema através de um evento de forma parcial mas nunca de forma total, pois se pudesse resolve-lo seria um requisito funcional.

**Opção 2** (O Mais correto)

> Os **RF** (Requisitos funcionais) se aplicam quando os usuários interagem diretamente com o sistema através dos eventos, e que quando ocorre alguma interação de forma indireta mas que afeta o usuário nesse caso aplicasse o conceito de **RNF** (Requisitos Não funcionais)

## Contexto de um exemplo usado

O exemplo:

Imagine que o seu sistema deva ser capaz de cadastrar todos os vôos possíveis entre todos as viagens nacionais, dessa forma ela deve ser capaz de informar o horário de embarque e desembarque, o numero do vôo, se vai fazer conexão ou ponte aérea dentre outro detalhes... O sistema deverá ser capaz de reajustar os horários dos voos caso ocorra atrasos.

Baseado nesse pequeno contexto podemos elencar alguns RF(Requisito Funcional).

**RF01**: Cadastrar voos

**RF02**: Cadastrar passageiros

**RF03**: Cadastrar rotas

**RF04**: Cadastrar estados brasileiros (locais de origem e destino)

---

Agora partindo para o lado negro da força, Um exemplo de RNF(Requisito Não Funcional)

**RNF01**: Prevenção quanto a atrasos.

Exemplos de motivo de um atraso: Más condições no tempo, atrasando o voo ou até mesmo cancelando-o.

## Dúvida

A respeito dessa  **explicação sobre requisito não funcional** e a **respeito ao exemplo** usado, é correto afirmar ambas estão de fato corretas?

Na época a atividade não foi corrigida e fiquei na dúvida, e hoje ao estudar novamente a respeito do conteúdo, deparei-me com a necessidade de uma resposta.

Comment: Não é uma questão adequadamente classificada como *projeto-de-software*. Remover esta marca poderá facilitar a localização de questões.

Answer (score 2):

> A respeito dessa explicação sobre requisito não funcional e a respeito
>   ao exemplo usado, é correto afirmar ambas estão de fato corretas?

Não, na verdade **requisito não funcional** não tem haver com eventos que não podem ser previstos, primeiro vamos ver a definição de requisitos:

[Requisitos não funcionais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requisito_n%C3%A3o_funcional), "são os requisitos relacionados ao uso da aplicação em termos de desempenho, usabilidade, confiabilidade, segurança, disponibilidade, manutenção e tecnologias envolvidas. Estes requisitos dizem respeito a como as funcionalidades serão entregues ao usuário do software." Ou seja, **requisitos não funcionais** são requisitos em que o usuário não interage diretamente com ele.

[Requisito funcional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requisito_funcional), "define uma função de um sistema de software ou seu componente. O requisito funcional representa o quê o software faz, em termos de tarefas e serviços." Ou seja, **requisitos funcionais** são requisitos em que o usuário interage diretamente com ele, como você disse, cadastro de voos, cadastro de passageiros...

No seu exemplo, eu mudaria o **RNF01** para ser algo como, "Caso as condições climáticas não estejam favoráveis, todo processamento de atraso de voos devem ser executados em menos de 20 segundos"

No exemplo acima, não tem haver com o fato da condição climática estar ruim, mas sim com o fato de, implicitamente, sem interação com o usuário, todos voos serem reagendados em um determinado período de tempo.

Comment: Discordo que atrasar vôos em caso de mau tempo seja RNF. Para mim isso é uma ação que o stakeholder quer que o sistema faça, ou seja, RF. Agora o requisito do sistema ser robusto, responsivo (no sentido de ter resposta rápida) e com código fácil de manter seriam RNF (ou seja, as "maneiras" como o sistema vai entregar seus RF).

Comment: Pela resposta apresentada, é possível concluir que os requisitos funcionais se aplicam quando os usuários interagem diretamente com o sistema através dos eventos (ou alguma ação), e que quando ocorre alguma interação de forma indireta mas que afeta o usuário, nesse caso aplicasse o conceito de RNF (caso do atraso nos voos por exemplo). é isso?

Comment: @Piovezan, minha intenção não foi o requisito em si, mas todo processamento por trás dele e a forma implícita que ele faz, acho que não fui feliz no exemplo. (requisito mal levantado) ;P, Editei, veja se ficou melhor, por favor.

Comment: @JonathasB.C. Essa é a ideia, mas ele é independente de condições externas que o sistema preveja ou não. A grosso modo. é aquilo que não é funcional para o usuário.

Comment: @Barbetta Ficou melhor, porém quanto ao exemplo de envio de email para RNF eu estou em dúvida. Olhei a [wikipedia em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requisito_n%C3%A3o_funcional) e não parece se encaixar em nenhum caso citado nela. RNF geralmente se refere a "qualidades" do software, como ser portável, ser robusto, já enviar email não é uma qualidade, seria RF também.

Comment: @Piovezan Acho que estou muito ruim de requisitos hoje, a ideia do envio de e-mail é usabilidade do envio de e-mail, e também segurança da confirmação do cadastro. Acredito que seja melhor remover essa parte para não gerar confusão.